# golang tests executed with other go version than the one that was set up

Tags: go, github, testing, github-actions

I have the following steps in a github actions workflow

```
      - name: setup go ${{ steps.go-version.outputs.minimal }}
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with: 
          go-version: ${{ steps.go-version.outputs.minimal }}


      - name: run unit tests
        run: go test -race -cover -v ./... -run Unit
```

The output of the first one:

```
Run actions/setup-go@v2
Setup go stable version spec 1.14
Attempting to download 1.14...
(...)
GOROOT="/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.14.15/x64"
(...)
```

which is indeed the version in my `go.mod`

However, in the output of the second one:

```
Run go test -race -cover -v ./... -run Unit
  go test -race -cover -v ./... -run Unit
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    GOROOT: /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.18.2/x64
```

Why does the second one run with `go` `1.18`

Comment: Did you try using the `check-latest: false` input field with the `actions/setup-go`? Setting it to false might resolve your problem (reference: https://github.com/actions/setup-go#check-latest-version).

Comment: You could also use directly the action `go-version-file` input field instead of an output from another step, to get and use the go version directly from your project `go.mod` file (reference: https://github.com/actions/setup-go#getting-go-version-from-the-gomod-file)

Comment: Sorry for maybe stating the obvious but I'd note for the next guy stumbling upon this question that the semantics of the Go version set in `go.mod` is not "pinning" but rather setting the lowest required set of the language and toolchain features. As an example, the toolchain of the Go 1.18 distribution will happily compile your code and tests instead of refusing doing that.

Comment: This could be [this bug](https://github.com/actions/setup-go/issues/107) from the `setup-go` action. Might be fixable with setting the $PATH as suggested in the issue

Comment: …and for that matter here at my $dayjob we have our CI set up for some of our Go projects that it runs the main jobs using the currently "blessed" Go release, and also a job doing `go build` and `go test -run=none` using the lowest supported Go release—to catch possible backward incompatibilities crept during the development.